# ASP.NET middleware invoke another action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-middleware

with ASP.NET 6 Web API project, i write a middleware to test action invoke.

```
public class RequestResponseMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
            // need server side url rewrite
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path == "/weatherforecast/Test") 
            {
                context.Request.Path = PathString.FromUriComponent("/weatherforecast/User");

                context.SetEndpoint(endpoint: null);
                var routeValuesFeature = context.Features.Get<IRouteValuesFeature>();
                if (routeValuesFeature is not null)
                {
                     routeValuesFeature.RouteValues = null!;
                }
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
     }
}
```

When client post to `https://localhost:7290/weatherforecast/Test`, i want it will invoke method `/weatherforecast/User"`.

When using method `context.Response.Redirect`, method `/weatherforecast/User` will be inovked. but the request will case another url redirect.

Is it possile direct inovke `/weatherforecast/User` at server side.

**---update---**

I have downloaded asp.net core source code ,and checked out the **RewriteMiddleware** code, and it seams reset r**equest.Path** , likes

```
     context.Request.Path = PathString.FromUriComponent("/weatherforecast/User");

     context.SetEndpoint(endpoint: null);
     var routeValuesFeature = context.Features.Get<IRouteValuesFeature>();
     if (routeValuesFeature is not null)
     {
         routeValuesFeature.RouteValues = null!;
     }
```

then call

```
   _next.Invoke(context);
```

but ,it not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I think you want to use url rewrite instead of url redirect, check this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#regex-examples) to learn difference. So you can use rewrite middleware to achieve it.

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
               .AddRewrite("weatherforecast/Test", "weatherforecast/User", true);
app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
```

In above middleware, If url contains `weatherforecast/Test`, Project will invoke `weatherforecast/User` at server side directly.

Comment: Is it possible write direct rewrite code inside my middleware, not use any 3rd middleware ?

Comment: In older versions, you can use `context.request.path=xxxx` to achieve url rewrite in your custom middleware, But it doesn't work in .Net6. `app.UseRewriter();` is the middleware officially provided by Microsoft, It is powerful and safety, So I highly recommend you to use this middleware directly.

Comment: yes, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite works fine. but , i really want do it myself. any help ?

Comment: Sry, From Microsoft Document, You can custom rewrite rules. But because `context.request.path=xxxx` doesn't work now, I don't think you can custom rewrite middleware.

Comment: You can post a issue about this source code in asp.net core github, Maybe the Microsoft developer will help you to find the source code.

Comment: yes, i have posted an issue.  Thanks.